# network profiles in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: network-manager, proxy, lan, automation, ip-address

I use a wired connection at home and in college. But at home i set my ipV4 settings to automatic DHCP whereas in college I need to manually enter the ip address, subnet and gateway and i also need to change proxy settings.

So whenever I go home, i need to change system settings to no proxy and also need to change the ip address settings, and when i go to college, I need to enter an automatic configuration url in the proxy settings and manual tcp/ip configurations.

Is there anyway I can combine these 2 processes, So that when i connect to a wired network in college, my proxy settings are set according to what i need in college and similarly at home. Is it possible to extend this automation to wireless networks also? it will be really helpful for me.

Comment: So its not possible? As far as i know, system proxy settings is just a variable right. It is built right into the browser. So can we not change the system proxy with different profiles? Anybody?

Comment: Ok. So i have set up 2 wired connection profiles properly for college. How do I modify the proxy settings depending on the profile as soon as the laptop is connected to a wired connection??