# Setting proxy variables automatically for different Network Profiles

Tags: networking, network-manager, proxy, system-settings

I have two network profiles for wired connections in the network manager:

```
  1. Home_Lan--> automatic dhcp requires No Proxy
  2. Hostel_Lan--> manual ip settings requires an automatic proxy url
```

Now, I can see these profiles in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections folder.
I checked [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OnNetworkConnectionRunScript) on using the ifup.d and ifdown.d scripts to run user defined scripts for specific tasks. I understand bits of it.

I want to be able to make a script and run it on the ifup event depending upon the network profile in my network manager. I understand that the ifup.d scripts responds to interfaces defined in the /etc/network/interfaces file. However my /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback
```

So my network profiles are listed in the network manager folder and not in the /etc/network/interfaces file. There is also a NetworkManager.conf file which says:

```
 [ifupdown]
 managed=false
```

I checked the NetworkManager [manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man5/NetworkManager.conf.5.html) and itsays that the **ifupdown = true|false** " Controls  whether interfaces listed in the 'interfaces' file are managed by NetworkManager.  If  set  to  true, then interfaces listed in /etc/network/interfaces are managed by NetworkManager."

Now I am relatively new to ubuntu and I do not really play around with settings, I am just not able to put it all together. What am I missing?

Comment: In short, do you mean to say that when you click on `Home LAN`, `proxy settings` should be disabled and when you click on `Hostel LAN`, your `proxy settings` should be enable?

Comment: Exactly @Jobin, I want to specify system proxy automatically with lan profiles!

Comment: Please don't post more than question to ask the same thing. Instead, you can *edit* your [original question](http://askubuntu.com/q/233156/22949) to add more information. Thanks.